# Limit/strip and extend embedded fields in document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have an app where the `User` can have multiple roles inside a `Room`. I want to have a relation/embedding between them where I want to have, besides the normal fields embedded from the User, one more called `role`. For example:

```
irb(main):001:0> @user
=> #<User _id: 52c9d44d72616e19bf000000, name: "ranisalt">
```

And...

```
irb(main):001:0> @room
=> #<Room _id: 52ca3a7872616e2204000000, name: "Test Room", users: [#<User _id: 52c9d44d72616e19bf000000, name: "ranisalt", role: "admin">, (...)]
```

(mind the 'role: "admin"')

How is it possible to add this one more field to the user inside the `room`?

Also, I'm using Facebook authentication, so my user has lots of data that aren't useful for the room, for example `provider`, `oauth_token`, `oauth_expires_at`, etc. How can I strip these fields off when embedding the user? They use most of the space and will quickly fill the space without being useful.

I use Rails 4. If needed, ask for my models, I can show them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you're denormalizing rooms so aggressively? Instead of rooms holding onto users that magically acquire roles, why not have rooms embed roles that reference users?

```
class Room
  embeds_many :roles
end

class Role
  belongs_to :user
  field :type
  embedded_in :room
end

class User
  has_many :roles
end
```

Comment: Good approach, I really didn't think this way. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Nested Attributes

provide a mechanism for updating documents and their relations in a single operation, by nesting attributes in a single parameters hash. This is extremely useful when wanting to edit multiple documents within a single web form.

Please refer http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/nested_attributes.html#common

Which help you to build relationship across tables.

Thank you